# Scroll lock list when the border of the item reaches the center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-view

I need to create a horizontal list of big items that dont fit the screen and i need to block scroll when start or end of the item reached center of the screen until user click on the next or prev item.

Here the example of how it should work. On the left image scroll blocked to the left, user can scroll first item like it on the right image.

[image]